# How to query Couchbase 1.8 JSON?

Tags: ruby, nosql, couchbase

I am new to couchbase.

I am taking a look at the new Couchbase 2 beta version and the JSON docs, indexes, views, querys look just great.

Thing is that I have to develop under version 1.8 and I can't get the way to query my JSON objects. I am the using ruby client.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that Couchbase 1.8 does not support this functionality.